# Echo Show is showing offline in my Alexa App and my Browser and it's not working properly

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

Okay I have reset my echo show and I logged in my amazon account. But when I check my device on the companion app it appears offline (alexa app is up-to-date) also in my browser on the computer I get the same things.

Also, any settings or skills I make in my Echo show are reflected in my account and are visible through both the browser and companion app. However any skill or setting I try to make from the app/browser are NOT showing on my echo show.

Another thing, when I enable skills that require account linking, Alexa asks that I continue the process through my alexa app. When i go and enter my credentials to use the skill, the app said that it's linked now. However when I try to invoke the skill on echo show, Alexa says the app is not linked.

Any thoughts on how to handle this whole mess??

Comment: did you tried remove echo from your alexa app and re-setup the echo? https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201601770

Comment: @hasbi I have an Echo Show device, and I have tried resetting it a dozen times with the same results. It's still not working properly.